# im really new to react so i wanted to know what this cool text effect would look like if it was in react, could someone please help me with it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

https://codepen.io/Hyperplexed/pen/rNrJgrd

```js
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let interval = null;

document.querySelector("h1").onmouseover = event => {  
  let iteration = 0;
  
  clearInterval(interval);
  
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText
      .split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if(index < iteration) {
          return event.target.dataset.value[index];
        }
      
        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
      })
      .join("");
    
    if(iteration >= event.target.dataset.value.length){ 
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    
    iteration += 1 / 3;
  }, 20);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
/*   background-color: black; */
  margin: 0rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  font-size: clamp(3rem, 10vw, 10rem);
/*   color: white; */
  padding: 0rem clamp(1rem, 2vw, 3rem);
  border-radius: clamp(0.4rem, 0.75vw, 1rem);
}

h1:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

/* -- YouTube Link Styles -- */

body.menu-toggled > .meta-link > span {
  color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
}

#source-link {
  bottom: 60px;
}

#source-link > i {
  color: rgb(94, 106, 210);
}

#yt-link > i {
  color: rgb(239, 83, 80);
}

.meta-link {
  align-items: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 6px;
  bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;  
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 400ms, border-color 400ms;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.meta-link:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.meta-link > i, .meta-link > span {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.meta-link > span {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-value="GOOGLE DEVELOPER STUDENT CLUB">GOOGLE DEVELOPER STUDENT CLUB</h1>

<a id="source-link" class="meta-link" href="https://kprverse.com" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i>
  <span>Source</span>
</a>

<a id="yt-link" class="meta-link" href="https://youtu.be/W5oawMJaXbU" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
  <span>2 min tutorial</span>
</a>
```

the code in the above codepen link is written in plain html css js, i wanted to learn how to do it in react using hooks. if someone could let me know how to do it or do it and show it to me, it'd be of great help.

as i dont know react properly, im having a hard time implenting the effect in react.

Comment: Please go read [ask], among other things, it has some hints on how a halfway proper question title should be phrased.

Comment: Also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1427878) - we are not here to write tutorials on extended topics for you.

Comment: Why do you think hooks would be involved here at all? `<h1 onMouseOver={...}>GOOGLE DEVELOPER STUDENT CLUB</h1>`

Comment: @super cause i would be changing the state of the text right? i want the effect to happen when i hover over the text and i want the text to return back to its original state once the mouse moves somewhere else

Comment: @Kar If you look at the sandbox you posted the animation just continues until it's finished, no matter if you move the mouse off of it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ref to store the interval ID and the rest of the code is roughly the same.

```js
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

function App() {
  const intvl = React.useRef();
  function animateText(event) {
    let iteration = 0;
    clearInterval(intvl.current);
    intvl.current = setInterval(() => {
      event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText
        .split("")
        .map((letter, index) => {
          if (index < iteration) {
            return event.target.dataset.value[index];
          }
          return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
        })
        .join("");
      if (iteration >= event.target.dataset.value.length) {
        clearInterval(intvl.current);
      }
      iteration += 1 / 3;
    }, 30);
  }
  return <h1 data-value="HYPERPLEXED" onMouseOver={animateText}>HYPERPLEXED</h1>;
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App/>);
```

```css
body{display:grid;place-items:center;height:100vh;background-color:#000;margin:0;overflow:hidden}h1{font-family:'Space Mono',monospace;font-size:clamp(3rem, 10vw, 10rem);color:#fff;padding:0 clamp(1rem,2vw,3rem);border-radius:clamp(.4rem,.75vw,1rem)}h1:hover{background-color:#fff;color:#000}body.menu-toggled>.meta-link>span{color:#1e1e1e}#source-link{bottom:60px}#source-link>i{color:#5e6ad2}#yt-link>i{color:#ef5350}.meta-link{align-items:center;backdrop-filter:blur(3px);background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.05);border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);border-radius:6px;bottom:10px;box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);cursor:pointer;display:inline-flex;gap:5px;left:10px;padding:10px 20px;position:fixed;text-decoration:none;transition:background-color .4s,border-color .4s;z-index:10000}.meta-link:hover{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.1);border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2)}.meta-link>i,.meta-link>span{height:20px;line-height:20px}.meta-link>span{color:#fff;font-family:Rubik,sans-serif;font-weight:500}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Or just ditch the ref and use `event.target`?

Comment: @super The ref is for the interval, not the element. Although I suppose it's not technically necessary here either.

Comment: Ah, right. That makes more sense.